# Page rendering as per needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a simple template which includes a navigation panel, a search bar and a add user form.What I want to do is control the DOMs to render as per need. Like at first I want to render the navigation panel,then as user's click want to render search bar or show users list or add user form.

How to do it using javascript/jquery?

My template:

```
<div>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li class="show">Show</li>
    <li class="search">Search</li>
    <li class="add">Add</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Search Contacts</h1>
  <form id="searchInfo">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="searchMatch">
    <ul class="searchMatchList">

    </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Add Contacts</h1>
  <form id="contactInfo">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" />
    <input type="text" id="phnNumber" name="phnNumber" />
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
    <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="showContacts">
    <ul class="contactsList">
    
    </ul>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Put each section in its own HTML file and make an AJAX call to retrieve it when required. Note though, that this is unlikely to aid performance - assuming that's your goal. If anything it will probably make the site slower to load due to the increased traffic. Load once and cache the data is normally the better approach for small sites.

Comment: Is there any option just not dividing it,I want to keep it in one file.Is it possible ?@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: So more like a toggle in the UI to hide/show them instead of dynamically loading the HTML?

Comment: *"to render as per needed"* - you probably want to "show as per needed" rather than the specific term "render".

Comment: toggling would do. But can't I load a portion of my template dynamically, other portion later in that manner ?But if you know how to toggle you can tell me please?I would rather go for that.@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Yeah show would do in my case.Can you tell me how to do that and if you have time, tell me the difference between render and show?@freedomn-m

Comment: For websites it's generally: "render" = take the source "code" and generate ("render") HTML.  In many cases this will be generated by server-side code  such as php or Razor with server-side tags which get "rendered" into HTML.    For "show"/"toggle"/"hide" - the HTML already exists in the page and the `display` style is changed from `none` to `block` (for example).  Maybe using something like jquery's `$("#contactInfo").fadeIn()`